# what happens after the return statement in an if statement in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, return

I wanted to keep it short. What happens after it returns `true`? Does it stop the `for`-loop and return to the `do`-`while` loop? I'm very confused; please provide a detailed description.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        int pick;
        do 
        {
            pick = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
        } 
        while (numberGone(pick, gui.numbers, i)); 
        gui.numbers[i].setText("" + pick);
    }
    boolean numberGone(int num, JTextField[] pastNums, int count) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            if (Integer.parseInt(pastNums[i].getText()) == num) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes it will terminate the for loop, and return from the current method to the calling method.

Comment: And you can use [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class and it's [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) method to get integer random number, rather than using a combination of `Math.floor()` with `Math.random()`

Answer (score 2):

A method returns the control as soon as it hits the first `return` statement. Any code after the `return` statement will not be executed. So in your code:

```
boolean numberGone(int num, JTextField[] pastNums, int count) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            if (Integer.parseInt(pastNums[i].getText()) == num) 
            {
                // if this is executed, execution of this method will return from here
                return true;
            }
        }
        // this will be executed only when if statement is not executed and for loop finishes gracefully
        return false;
    }
```

Note: If you don't want to return from the method when your if condition is met and simply end the loop then use `break` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 1):

The function always exits when a `return` statement is encountered. No statement after that will be executed.
The only exception is `try catch finally` block.
`finally` block is always executed irrespective of whether `return` is encountered before it or not.